# Testing via Jasmine - new line after each step

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am new to the Jasmine library.

My aim is to print all the title of each step ("it") even if it passes. Moreover, I would like to write each step in a new line.

How do I do this?

```
 it('type manager id ', async() => {
    await useful.clickAndWait(page, confEditOrder.openSaleToEdit, confMWpos.swipeCardUsrContinue);
    await sleep.sleep(confUtility.levelWait.selectorAppears);
    isAppear = await useful.isExist(page, confMWpos.swipeCardUsrContinue);
    await ta.inputSwipeCard.setText(confSeting.password.shiftsManager[useful.environments().station]);
    expect("Swipe card is opening: true").toBe(`Swipe card is opening: ${isAppear}`);
});
it('open menu ', async() => {
    // {
    // debugger;
    await useful.clickAndWait(page, confMWpos.swipeCardUsrContinue, confEditOrder.saveCustomer);
    if (customer.subService == "delivery")
        await useful.click(page, confEditOrder.saveCustomer);
    isAppear = await useful.isExist(page, confEditOrder.dealsButton);
    expect("menu is opening: true").toBe(`menu is opening: ${isAppear}`);
    // }
});
```

My output is

.F

And I wish to change that to be:

type manager id - passed 
open menu - failed

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At least show the code you want to test

Answer (score -1):

If you would like the tests to run in order, you need to change the `random` boolean.

Check out this exchange:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/36601

Although, to ensure the reliability of the unit tests, it is preferable to make the unit tests run in random order to ensure they don't rely on the order they run in.

Comment: Your "answer" has nothing to do with what I asked about. I'm asking about the console printing, not the order of the tests.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about me misunderstanding you. If you're using Karma to run your test, you can use this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter (https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter-example) to get what you want. Most likely there is a plugin like that (a reporter) to get what you want for the test runner you're using.